# R sequence format from raw sequence to shortened code

Tags: r, sequence

In R i can write a sequence of 1 - 9 like `1:9` and it will output `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)`.

I want to do the reverse. If i have a sequence of `c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)` is there any way to get `1:9` as an output? Preferably in a dynamic way, so that for example `c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9)` becomes `c(1:4, 6:9)`?

Comment: What is the type of the desired output? Character I assume.

Comment: yes, character. i'm writing a script that "writes" scripts by itself. so i'm just gathering methods to output R code - which would be character strings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
sapply(split(x, cumsum(c(1, diff(x)) > 1)), function(x) paste(range(x), collapse = ":"))

    0     1 
"1:4" "6:9"
```

Answer (score 1):

We can use `tapply`

```
tapply(x, cumsum(c(TRUE, diff(x) > 1)), FUN = 
         function(x) paste(min(x), max(x), sep=":"))
 #   1     2 
 #"1:4" "6:9"
```

#### data

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,6,7,8,9)
```

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps a roundabout way, but you can use the `head` and `tail` functions to get the first and last item of the vector.

```
> x <- c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
> tail(x, n=1)
[1] 9
> head(x, n=1)
[1] 1
> head(x, n=1):tail(x, n=1)
[1] 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
```